# Set cron job dynamically base from different user timezone

Tags: laravel, cron

In laravel 7, I setup cronjobs that runs base from different users specific timezone.
Here's the exact code:

```
foreach (User::role('admin')->get() as $user) {
        /* with queue job */
        $schedule->command('weekly-survey:send')->timezone($user->timezone)->weekly()->wednesdays()->at('8:00');
        $schedule->command('update:surveys-completed')->timezone($user->timezone)->daily();


        $schedule->command('trial:reminder')->timezone($user->timezone)->dailyAt('7:45');

        $schedule->command('trial:ends')->timezone($user->timezone)->dailyAt('23:00');
        $schedule->command('subscribe:customer')->timezone($user->timezone)->dailyAt('23:45');

        $schedule->command('update:user-invoice')->timezone($user->timezone)->everyMinute();
        $schedule->command('employees:update-status')->timezone($user->timezone)->everyMinute();

        $schedule->command('subscription:update-quantity')->timezone($user->timezone)->daily();

        $schedule->command('update:freeze-account')->timezone($user->timezone)->dailyAt('22:45');
        $schedule->command('send:upcoming-survey-notification')->timezone($user->timezone)->weeklyOn(1, '8:00');
        $schedule->command('surveys:end-soon')->timezone($user->timezone)->dailyAt('8:00');

        /* end with queue job */

        /* without queue */
        $schedule->command('amazon:get-send-qouta')->timezone($user->timezone)->dailyAt('23:55');
        $schedule->command('amazon:get-statistics')->timezone($user->timezone)->dailyAt('23:55');

        $schedule->command('update:customer-success-table')->timezone($user->timezone)->everyMinute();

        $schedule->command('csm:prev-month-active')->timezone($user->timezone)->lastDayOfMonth('23:59');
        $schedule->command('update:monthly-earning')->timezone($user->timezone)->lastDayOfMonth('23:59');


        $schedule->command('update:subscription-status')->timezone($user->timezone)->everyMinute();

        $schedule->command('retrieve:past-due-subscription')->timezone($user->timezone)->dailyAt('23:59');

        $user = new User();
        $user->accountNotificationsSchedule($schedule);

        $schedule->command('horizon:snapshot')->timezone($user->timezone)->everyFiveMinutes();

        /* end without queue */

        \Log::info("Cron entry successfully executed!");
    }
```

Do this code safe to run? First I loop through all users where has admin role and then pass user time zone to each of the command. I'm sure that this code will infinitely run for as long as the server is alive. I just want to have an alternative safe approach.

Comment: As you know opinion based questions are not allowed on SO. I would not schedule a command for each user, iI would run schedule one command and select the users that need to run at that time in the command instead.

Comment: How would you do that? @GertB.

Comment: @TokstiDatsReady launch a job every minute (or 5, or what you need, keep it low but don't stress the server) that gathers the users that are in the timezone you want the process to start for. If in that minute there is no user then your job will start and end instantly (if you implement that correctly obv)

Comment: You mean I will run job once with users in different timezone and then should end instantly after finished iterating users with different timezone? @FabioR.

Comment: Nono, my idea was to launch the job every minute or so and in there collect all users you want to modify based on timezones and process only those. The next minute (or what you chose) the job runs again and if there's no one to process it just ends saving server resources. For example: Let's say i want to send something to everyone at 4.00 PM. Every hour (you will use what you need) i collect every user that lives in the timezone where it's currently 4.00 PM and do what i want to do. The next hour i will take the next timezone and so on

Comment: @TokstiDatsReady Edit the question and paste it there, it's more readable and if that's correct you can just edit it out and paste it in an answer

Comment: Done. I just answer my own question. @FabioR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I implemented and it works.

```
public function handle(TimezoneRepository $timezoneRepository) 
{ 
 // get user's unique timezone 
 $timezones = $timezoneRepository->getUniqueTimezones();

 foreach ($timezones as $timezone) { 
   $date = Carbon::now($timezone); 
   // send only on Wednesday at 8:00 am 
   if ($date->isWednesday() && $date->hour == 8 && $date->minute == 0) { 
    Survey::SendSurvey(); 
  } 
 } 
}
```